# compare column values only with identical datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a long df from 07:00:00 to 20:00:00 (df1) and a short df with only fractions of the long one (df2) (identical datetime index values).

I would like to compare the groupsize values of the two data frames.

The datetime index, id, x, and y values should be identical.

I can i do this?

df1:

```
Out[180]: 

date                     id       gs   x    y                                          
2019-10-09 07:38:22.139  3166     nan  248  233
2019-10-09 07:38:25.259  3166     nan  252  235
2019-10-09 07:38:27.419  3166     nan  253  231
2019-10-09 07:38:30.299  3166     nan  251  232
2019-10-09 07:38:32.379  3166     nan  251  233
2019-10-09 07:38:37.179  3166     nan  228  245
2019-10-09 07:39:49.498  3167     nan  289  253
2019-10-09 07:40:19.099  3168     nan  288  217
2019-10-09 07:40:38.779  3169     nan  278  139
2019-10-09 07:40:39.899  3169     nan  279  183
...
2019-10-09 19:52:53.959  5725     nan  190  180
2019-10-09 19:52:56.439  5725     nan  193  185
2019-10-09 19:52:58.919  5725     nan  204  220
2019-10-09 19:53:06.440  5804     nan  190  198
2019-10-09 19:53:08.919  5804     nan  200  170
2019-10-09 19:53:11.419  5804     nan  265  209
2019-10-09 19:53:16.460  5789     nan  292  218
2019-10-09 19:53:36.460  5806     nan  284  190
2019-10-09 19:54:08.939  5807     nan  404  226
2019-10-09 19:54:23.979  5808     nan  395  131
```

df2:

```
Out[181]: 

date                     id    gs   x    y                                       
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3479  2.0  353  118.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3477  2.0  315   92.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3473  2.0  351  176.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3476  2.0  318  176.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3386  0.0  148  255.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3390  0.0  146  118.0
2019-10-09 11:20:01.418  3447  0.0  469  167.0
2019-10-09 11:20:03.898  3447  0.0  466  169.0
2019-10-09 11:20:03.898  3390  0.0  139  119.0
2019-10-09 11:20:03.898  3477  2.0  316   93.0
```

Expected output should be a dataframe with columns "date", "id", "x", "y", "gs(df1)", "gs(df2)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a Merge where everything is equal but make sure to reset index so its part of the merge condition

```
df1_t = df1.reset_index()
df2_t = df1.reset_index()

results = df1_t.merge(df2_t, left_on = ['date', 'ids', 'x', 'y'],
                      right_on = ['date', 'ids', 'x', 'y'], 
                      indicator = True).reset_index()

print(results)
```

`results` will have the rows on `df1` that are in `df2`.

Comment: df2_temp is here what here?

Comment: Sorry was a type, is `df2`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it gives me ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects. So I have both datatime indexes, and df2 is a fraction of df1 where the dateitme index is identical. I only want the data rows from df1 that have identical index, id, x, and y

Comment: Oh, check the edit I made, my bad I understood the problem incorrectly.